# Solve for a function given a Taylor series

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am solving this problem for 3 hours and I really need some help.

How to find a function given the Taylor series: $$ h(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \{2-(-1)^k\}x^k.$$

I tried getting the derivative of the summation and use the geometric series which is $f(x)= \dfrac{1}{1-x}$, but I still didn't get the answer.

Comment: Split the summation

Comment: did u mean it would be equal to summation of {2-(1)^k} and summation of x^k? but the summation of {2-(1)^k} doesn't equate to anything

Comment: @calcex You can't split a sum of products into a product of sums. But you **can**, under some circumstances, split a sum like so: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n+b_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$

Comment: $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {(2 - ( - 1)^k )x^k }  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {(2x^k  - ( - 1)^k x^k )}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {2x^k } - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^k x^k }  = 2\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {x^k } - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^k x^k }  =  \cdots 
$$

Comment: @calcex What is the expansion point?

Comment: @callculus42 It is a power series centered at $0$.

Comment: @Gary But the question is about Taylor series?

Comment: @callculus42 It is a Taylor series expansion about the origin. If it was a Taylor series about a point $a$ say, it would be in powers of $(x-a)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$ h(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \{2-(-1)^k\}x^k 
= 2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k - \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-x)^k$$

Note that the summation starts at $k=1$. You should deal with this appropriately.